# Getting Exception 'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure'

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect an Android app with a MySQL database using JDBC. I'm getting a Communication Link failure exception. I have added the MySQL JDBC connector jar file as a library and the MySQL server is on.

```java
package com.example.androidmysqlconnectionjdbc;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn_login, btn_register;
    EditText et_username, et_password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        et_password = findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        et_username = findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new RetrieveDataFromServer().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class RetrieveDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testing?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";
        String username = "XXX";
        String password = "XXX";
        Connection connection;
//implementation files('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar')

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception is", e.toString());
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isConnected) {

            if (isConnected) {
                Log.d("ConnectionStatus", "Connection successful");
                // You can perform database operations here
            } else {
                Log.e("ConnectionStatus", "Connection failed");
                // Display an error message to the user
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection to the database failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Exception I'm getting

2023-10-26 19:33:54.205 10198-10198 ConnectionStatus        com...le.androidmysqlconnectionjdbc  E  Connection failed
2023-10-26 19:37:57.741 10198-10241 Exception is            com...le.androidmysqlconnectionjdbc  E  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago

Comment: Please [reconsider your use of JDBC directly in an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android?r=Saves_AllUserSaves).

Comment: YEs, but I'm learning Android and for learning only I'm trying to connect with JDBC but getting this CommunicationsException

Comment: "I'm learning Android" -- have you considered learning Android using approaches that are perhaps more appropriate for Android?

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, I'm learning other approaches as well but this just makes me curious as I have tried a bunch of things but still this is not working, so just looking for a solution.

Comment: I notice you are trying to use the local loopback address to connect to MySQL. Where is your Android code running  and where is your MySQL server? If you are trying to connect to MySQL on host PC from emulator you can use [`10.0.2.2`](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking).

Comment: Your MySQL server is **not** running on your Android mobile (or emulator), so using 127.0.0.1 is not the correct host.